Change option after disable it in quasar select
I have select in quasar and after selecting an option in another field I want to disable one of the options and if it is selected then switch it to another option. I use the code below to disable the option but how do I change the selected option?
  <q-select 
                        dense
                        options-dense
                        borderless
                        :option-disable="(val) => optionDisable(val)"/>

.
optionDisable (val) {
      if (otherField === 'val1') {
        if (val.value === 'option1') {
          return true
        }
      } else {
        if (val.value === 'option2') {
          return true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false
},


To change the selected option when one of the options is disabled, you can use Quasar QSelect's updateSelected method to update the selected option. This can be done in the optionDisable function or in a separate function that is called when another option is selected.
Here is an example of how you can do this:
 <template>
      <div>
        <q-select 
          dense
          options-dense
          borderless
          v-model="selectedOption"
          :options="options"
          :option-disable="(val) => optionDisable(val)"
          @input="handleSelect"
        />
        <q-select
          dense
          options-dense
          borderless
          v-model="otherField"
          :options="otherFieldOptions"
        />
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          selectedOption: null,
          otherField: null,
          options: [
            { value: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },
            { value: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },
            { value: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' }
          ],
          otherFieldOptions: [
            { value: 'val1', label: 'Val 1' },
            { value: 'val2', label: 'Val 2' }
          ]
        }
      },
      methods: {
        optionDisable(val) {
          if (this.otherField === 'val1') {
            if (val.value === 'option1') {
              return true
            }
          } else {
            if (val.value === 'option2') {
              return true
            }
          }
          return false
        },
        handleSelect(value) {
          if (this.otherField === 'val1' && value === 'option1') {
            this.selectedOption = 'option3' // ou qualquer outra opção válida
          } else if (this.otherField === 'val2' && value === 'option2') {
            this.selectedOption = 'option3' // ou qualquer outra opção válida
          }
        }
      },
      watch: {
        otherField(newVal, oldVal) {
          if (newVal === 'val1' && this.selectedOption === 'option1') {
            this.selectedOption = 'option3' // ou qualquer outra opção válida
          } else if (newVal === 'val2' && this.selectedOption === 'option2') {
            this.selectedOption = 'option3' // ou qualquer outra opção válida
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>

In this example:
I added a watch to the otherField property to detect changes and adjust the selected option as needed.
I added the handleSelect method that will be called when the q-select is changed, allowing the selected option to be updated if the new option is disabled.
This way, when changing the value of otherField, the selected option will be adjusted if necessary, ensuring that a disabled option is never selected.
